# Question about FindKClique

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

Say we have a graph:

`g = CompleteGraph[5];`

and that we want to find all the triangles in `g`. I tried to use `FindKClique`, in the following way:

`FindKClique[g,1,{3},All]`

but it returns an empty list and I am not sure why. I must be misunderstanding something about `FindKClique` but I'm not sure what it is. The output I would expect to get is the following:

`Map[First,FindCycle[g,{3},All],{2}]`

> {{3, 2, 4}, {3, 5, 4}, {1, 5, 3}, {2, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 5}, {1, 5, 2}, {1,
>      3, 2}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 5, 4}}

Can someone explain why `FindKClique` is not doing what I thought it would?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs of [`FindKClique`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindKClique.html),

> A k-clique is a maximal set of vertices that are at a distance no greater than k from each other.

There are no *maximal* cliques that are 3-cliques in $K_5$.

I suggest you use `IGCliques` from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), which finds all cliques, not just maximal ones.

```
<< IGraphM`

IGCliques[CompleteGraph[5], {3}]
(* {{3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 4, 5}} *)
```

If you only need triangles (not larger cliques), you can also use `IGTriangles`, which is going to be faster.

```
IGTriangles[CompleteGraph[5]]
(* {{1, 2, 5}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5}} *)
```

If you need to find sets of vertices no more than distance $k$ away, as with `FindKClique`, first connect each vertex to its $k$-neighbourhood, then find normal cliques.

```
IGCliques[IGConnectNeighborhood[graph, k], {size}]
```